# Why using void method that open a file would not open it?

Tags: java, io

I define the method:

```
Public static void openFile(String fileName, PrintWriter stream) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    stream = new PrintWriter (fileName);
}
```

I call the method:

```
PrintWriter toFile = null;
    try 
    {
       openFile ("data.txt", toFile);
    }
```

Why after the openFile is executed, the value of toFile is still null?

Comment: why not return the `PrinterWriter` instead of using it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes I can. But just want to give it a try with void method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `toFile`, you're passing a reference to the `PrintWriter`. But the reference itself gets copied: the `toFile` inside your method is a reference to the same object, but it's a different reference.

Modifying `toFile` inside the method changes this copy, but doesn't alter the original. The copy gets thrown away when the method terminates.

This is intentional, and it's there to protect you. When you pass an argument to a method, you should be able to rely on that argument not changing. If I execute

```
doSomethingToElement(i);
```

where `i` is an index into something, I really don't want the possibility that the value of `i` will be changed inside the method.

It also helps the compiler with optimising things.

In C, you could pass a pointer to the reference, so that it could be changed inside the method, or you could just pass the reference if you didn't want the possibility that it would change. But in Java, everything is passed by value.

Note that the concepts need careful thinking through: `toFile` is a *reference*, but you're passing that reference *by value*.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are [passed by value](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=Ae1cVKPyIImxyQS_-4LYDA&ved=0CDEQFjAF&sig2=YWuc2z1z6QLPaFozGCKd5w&usg=AFQjCNH3ZpFzsVK6IC23Dar-qooixDbUMw) in Java, not by reference. So when you assign stream in your method, it only pertains to the method you are in, and won't set the value of the variable you passed in.